# How do I paint (wrap) a texture around a mesh with even texture dimensions?

Tags: texture-painting

Blender Version 2.8

I try to paint a texture on a surface and want to have the same texture, no matter what zoom, distance or face direction I use.

I played around with the different texture mapping options:

**Stencil:** disoriented, once the face is not perfect aligned with view, size depends on distance to face

**Tiled:** disoriented, once the face is not perfect aligned with view, size depends on distance to face and the size of the brush

**3D:** disoriented once the face is not perfect aligned to x-y axis.

So far it seems 3D is the right otion (as stated in another thread I lost the link). But how do I solve the disorientation?
[image]
As one can see, it looks like the texture is projected in z direction only and any face not x-y direction is disoriented.
So far there might be an option to project the texture not in global but in normals direction, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I think Tiled or Stencil are the good solutions, but yes you need to stay at the same distance, it looks like there's no lock for the texture brush that would allow to keep the same texture size whatever zoom distance you choose. Also maybe to bring some small corrections at the end you could use the Clone brush.

Comment: Argg ... So maybe the best solution would be to invest some minutes into a nice UV seam to get a mostly even sized 2D picture and paint the majority on the 2D side. The final corrections on the seams can be done in 3D then.

My major issue is drawing a fabric texture seemingly seamless around a garment. Painting a sleeve becomes a nightmare since any brush will always get a touch to the currently sloped faces.

Comment: mmh seems a bit complicated

Comment: Is your final desired result to be this icosphere, or are you practicing toward a different result? if you can prepare a tileable seamless texture as a base, then it does become easier to align if using quads in the model. Proper UV unwrapping and scaling the uv to get the proper ratio of detail to polygon then woudl mean you wouldn't need to paint it until after you baked it down from the node tree to a new mapped image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest with tiled patterns like this that you actually avoid manually painting until you have to deal with seams on your object. If you can use quads on your mesh, reset the UV unwrap for mapping all faces to a single tiled texture and you can then make use of Follow Active Quads to change up the mapping. Scale the UV up and down in the UV editor and you can manipulate the mapping with realtime feedback.
[image]

Comment: Thank You!

I think that's a possible way to create a starting texture to paint on.

I'll try it out in the next few days and let you know whether it worked for me.

Comment: This is how I start a lot of textures, mapping different uv schemes and then baking down to one I can paint on.

Comment: Tested and found for good!
For other here a few comments, I struggled with my 200.000 vertices HighPoly model:

1.To draw the basic texture for your HighPoly model, you have to double the model. The main model with the desired UV fitting in one tile stays untouched and is the bake target!, The second, temporarily is for tweaking the UV map and can be deleted once you have the start texture.

2. The UV doesn't need to fit into the tile, The tile simply is repeated.

3. The most left source in the nodes above is not needed. The current UV mapping seems to be used as default.

Comment: I always use multiple up layers for full effect so still use the up node to indicate which one especially when baking down.